# Error when connecting to SQL Azure database with SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am getting the following error connecting to a SQL Azure database with SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio (I have tried from multiple machines from different networks)

[image]

I have no problems regarding firewall rules.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

I have tried to change connection information in the "Connect To server" dialog and it worked. More specifically instead of specifying a username for the connection I wrote `dbusername@server` in the username dialog.

Apart from the fact that the problem is solved I would like to really know why this has changed from yesterday and just find a better explanation

Comment: Is your SQL server under high load? This error message occurs sometimes for me, if I insert many data at once.

Comment: Not at the moment. It is a test server where I did some load tests yesterday. Is there any way to connect to the server and execute queries without SSMS?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I never saw that behaviour you are describing, the error usually indicates network connectivity issues. Unfortunatly you cannot view the logs. If you can reproduce that problem I would consider it as bug in their configurations. Are you using a preview version of Azure SQL and do you have the most recent version of the SSDT installed?